# Complex Rails app with new ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have adopted a Rails app that has a lot of complex relationships. We started getting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error and am trying to track it down.

Is there a way to `wrap` relationships in a `begin ... rescue` block to determine which one is causing us problems similar to what they are doing here for a find method? Or is there a way to log that exact SQL call that is getting the RecordNotFound error?

### Edit

I am not able to find post I was referencing but I really just need to find the relationship that is busted. In my logs, I just see that it is rendering the template for 'not_found' records but I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: I think you forgot to include a link when you said "similar to what they are doing here"

Comment: looks like you need some advise in debugging http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Show us your relationships & log

Answer (score 0):

Without your relationships & logs, everything is conjecture; but if you're getting a `RecordNotFound` error - it basically means you're trying to load a record which doesn't exist in your db

---

> Is there a way to wrap relationships in a begin ... rescue block to
>   determing which one is causing us problems similar to what they are
>   doing here for a find method

No - a better way to debug is to find the logs in your `/log/development.log` file & then display the response here.

A pointer is that I don't think the relationship will be the issue. The relationship will just return null if nothing is there; the `RecordNotFound` error will be a result of `ActiveRecord` not being able to find the requested resource

EG

```
@post = Post.find 13 #-> RecordNotFound if a post with id 13 does not exist
```

If you post your logs & code, it will be the best way to help us solve your issue!

Comment: thx - so I understand your point, there's about 20 relationships with 10 calls in the log; all of them appear to be returning a result. I agree it's probably a data issue; it's just really frustrating that there's not a way in Rails to say "if you get a recordnotfound error, please highlight in different color" so it's incredibly obvious to the dev what is causing the problem.